# LG G3 proximity sensor half working

Tags: proximity-sensor, lg-g3

The past couple of days my proximity sensor has been playing up and after using [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en_GB) to check if it's working I can see that when looking at my phone at a normal distance it shows 5cm, and if I wave my hand at any distance (within reason) it instantly jumps to 0cm.

The problem though is that it does not then return to 5cm for about 30 seconds to a minute which makes it very difficult to use the phone. I can't end a phone call until this resets itself. Additionally, I can't unlock my phone until this resets either. I don't know why this occurs, but if I wake the phone the screen shuts off after about one second making it impossible to unlock it until the sensor resets.

So it seems as if the sensor is faulty - or there's something else going on. Any ideas? I've not had any major drops, a few very minor but nothing that would cause any scratches or other damage.

p.s. I do have a screen protector, however removing this makes no difference, and I've had this on for weeks and not had a problem until now.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this video [LG G4 Proximity Sensor Calibration (No Root,No App needed) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPKL1U94L9Y).

Go into the secret menu of the phone and do as explained in the video. It worked for me. Good luck.